# Action and ActionMap - Explain me this behavior

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, key-bindings, abstract-action

I have an `Action`

```
SampleAction a = new SampleAction("foo", null);
```

Then I add it to a Button, and to an ActionMap

```
JButton b = new JButton(a);
b.getActionMap().put("bar", a);
b.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F1"), "bar");
```

I put a trace (`System.out.println("Action [" + e.getActionCommand() + "] performed!");`) inside the Action. When I press the button with mouse it shows

```
Action [foo] performed!
```

But when i use <kbd>F1</kbd>, it shows:

```
Action [null] performed!
```

Why?

---

```
class SampleAction extends AbstractAction
{
    public SampleAction(String text, Icon icon) {
        super(text, icon);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Action [" + e.getActionCommand() + "] performed!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see the `SimpleAction` class, posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @DavidKroukamp there you go

Comment: why questions are hard to answer (can't see into the brains of the swing team devs, not even in the presence, far less in the past :-) If an Action doesn't have its actionCommmand explicitly set, it defaults to SomeThing. That SomeThing is different at the two locations (in AbstractButton.fireActionEvent vs. SwingUtilities.notifyAction) where the actionEvent is created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I am misunderstanding You should call `getActionCommand` on the instance of your `JButton` via `ae.getSource()` where as you are calling `getActionCommand()` on the `ActionEvent`:

```
  SampleAction a = new SampleAction("foo", null);

  JButton b = new JButton(a);
  b.getActionMap().put("bar", a);
  b.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F1"), "bar");

class SampleAction extends AbstractAction
{
    public SampleAction(String text, Icon icon) {
    super(text, icon);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Action [" + ((JButton)e.getSource()).getActionCommand() + "] performed!");
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to @Kleopatra this might be a better way:

```
SampleAction a = new SampleAction("foo", null);

JButton b = new JButton(a);
b.getActionMap().put("bar", a);
b.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F1"), "bar");

 class SampleAction extends AbstractAction {

        public SampleAction(String text, Icon icon) {
            super(text, icon);

            putValue(Action.ACTION_COMMAND_KEY, text);//'foo' will be printed when button clicekd/F1 pressed
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Action [" + e.getActionCommand() + "] performed!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: hmm ... that's not really answering the question (as I perceive it, anyway :-) - it's more about the difference of the _actionCommand_ when the same Action is used as the buttons (that is performed on clicking) vs. used in the actionMap.

Comment: I put `JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW` but it is still printing `null` when pressing F1

Comment: oh now it is `:P`  I just thought I was doing something wrong with the keybinding. `:)` But then it seems ok.

Comment: question transmorphed - and ... again one of those _don't_, I'm afraid :-) A button's internal default creation of the actionCommand is an undocumented implementation detail (and not the cleverest thingy to do in itself: names might be localized and change - not a good candidate for an identifier) - application code which needs the command _must not_ rely on such a windy property. Instead, set it on the _action_ Plus, it defeats the whole purpose of the Action: it's designed to be used independently of the view (could be a JTextField f.i. or anything else)

Comment: @kleopatra the only other solution I know of would be than to use a mnemonic but that will force the use of ALT+Key seqeunce

Comment: hmm ... what's wrong with myAction.putValue(Action.ACTION_COMMAND_KEY, "fooCommand")?

Answer (score 1):

I have no access to your `SampleAction`, but I guess the "foo" text you pass in the constructor is used as a text and has nothing to do with the action command.

If you look into the `AbstractButton` class from which `JButton` extends, you see

```
public String getActionCommand() {
    String ac = getModel().getActionCommand();
    if(ac == null) {
        ac = getText();
    }
    return ac;
}
```

This method is used when creating the `ActionEvent` which is passed to the action. When you click the button, this method is called and I assume `ac` is `null` but the `getText()` method returns the `"foo"` you used in your `SampleAction` class.

When you trigger the action directly by pressing F1, you bypass this mechanism and simply trigger the action. If you want to avoid this, you can add an `Action` to the `ActionMap` of the `JButton` which simply does `JButton#doClick`, which is the API call to perform a "click" on the button

Comment: Oh so that's not important. I just thought I was doing something wrong with the keybinding. :)

Comment: the "however..." is a bit misleading: nothing by-passed, just the ActionEvent created at a different location, see SwingUtilities.notifyAction :) Defaults are just ... defaults, and uncontrollable (and here even undocumented). If we need to control them, the only way out is to configure the action with it.